# Facebook API Get Location's info

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook PHP API V2.9 and want to get the user's location city, country_code, latitude, etc.
Permissions for the app are granted by Facebook. This is how the code looks:

```
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=first_name,last_name,picture,email,gender,location');
$userNode = $response->getGraphUser();

$fb_user_first_name     = $userNode->getField('first_name');
$fb_user_last_name      = $userNode->getField('last_name');
$fb_user_gender         = $userNode->getField('gender');
$fb_user_picture        = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_user_id.'/picture?type=large'; #$userNode->getField('picture')['url'];
$fb_user_email          = $userNode->getField('email');
$fb_user_city           = $userNode->getField('location');
$fb_user_country        = '';
$fb_user_country_code   = '';

// Get City
if(!empty($fb_user_city)) {
    $city_response  = $fb->get('/'.$fb_user_city['id'].'/locations?fields=city,country,country_code,latitude,longitude');
    $cityNode       = $city_response->getGraphObject();
}
```

However, the // Get City part ends in an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
> 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Unable to
> convert response from Graph to a GraphNode because the response looks
> like a GraphEdge. Try using GraphNodeFactory::makeGraphEdge()
> instead.' in /libs/Facebook/GraphNodes/GraphNodeFactory.php:224 Stack
> trace: #0 /libs/Facebook/GraphNodes/GraphNodeFactory.php(93):
> Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNodeFactory->validateResponseCastableAsGraphNode()
>
> ## 1 /libs/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php(289): Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNodeFactory->makeGraphNode(NULL) #2
>
> /libs/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php(273):
> Facebook\FacebookResponse->getGraphNode(NULL) #3
> /oauth/callback.facebook.php(129):
> Facebook\FacebookResponse->getGraphObject() #4 {main} thrown in
> /libs/Facebook/GraphNodes/GraphNodeFactory.php on line 224

The question is, why? I follow the instructions of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/location/ but it won't work...

Comment: It is locations. Not location. It may return more than one location.

Comment: Same. Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthenticationException' with message 'Unknown path components: /location'

Comment: I get back $userNode->getField('location'); but it only returns me the ID of the Location + "Name,Country". Which works, but is not the 100% perfect info I'd like to get. @WizKid

Comment: I'm saying that use locations. But because you get more than one result back you can't use getGraphObject. Use getGraphEdge instead.

Comment: @WizKid could you provide a small example on the case above? Would help a lot.

Comment: They gave you in https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/1385064818203695/ . If that is not working then show us the code and tell us the error